# How to extract files from saz file?

Tags: extract, fiddler, unzip, data-extraction

I exported a session from Fiddler to saz files. 
This session includes only jpg files and I'm wondering - **how can I extract the jpg files from saz quickly and easily**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to extract the JPEG files is to use Fiddler itself. Fiddler allows you to load a SAZ file (under `File/Load Archive..`).

[image]

Once loaded, just right-click on the HTTP message with the JPEG and select `Save/Response/Response Body...`.

[image]

If you want to do it the hard way, a SAZ file is just a zip file. Below is from the Fiddler [FAQ page](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/saz-files)

> SAZ files are simply specially formatted .ZIP files. If you rename a
>   .SAZ file to .ZIP, you can open it for viewing using standard ZIP
>   viewing tools.

According to the FAQ, the HTTP payload data is stored in a directory called `raw`. The JPEG data will be in one of the `sessid#_s.txt` files, but embedded in a HTTP response message. Strip the HTTP headers to get the JPEG (assuming there is no extra encoding in the HTTP message).

> sessid#_s.txt - contains the raw server request

Comment: Thx, but where, when and how to strip the HTTP header? in the extracted folder?

Comment: Added a comment about using Fiddler itself to extract the JPEG files. That is the easiest way to extract the JPEG files.

Comment: Can you explain where should I add the comment in Fiddler? I think I didn't understand.

Comment: Added a couple of Fiddler screen shots. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in the easiest way, it's impossible to save several images in one-time. which means, every single file required different save command, doesn't it?

Comment: You can select multiple messages at the same time with by Control+click each. Then when you do a save it will prompt for a new filename for each. Not ideal, but a bit quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler now requires a password to work, and I'm not willing to register.

First, I create a folder and put the .saz file inside
Second, I change to that directory and use unzip to extract the files because a saz file is a standard archive
Third, I open _index.htm with any browser and click the links in the index file

Have fun.